# How to evaluate contour integral $z^i $ over a unit circle

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

How to evaluate
$$\oint_{C}z^idz
$$
over a unit circle in complex plane.

I tried following.

t = angle theta

$$z = e^{it}$$

$$z^i = i \operatorname{Log} z = i \operatorname{Log} (e^{it})= i i t= - t$$

$$dz = i e^{it} dt$$

$$-i\oint_{C}te^{it}dt$$

Sorry for plain text, I dont know how to type math

Comment: Try $z=e^{i\theta}$...

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to mention how you define $z^i$.

Comment: Yes it is correct

Comment: The $dt$-integral is not over $C$. It ranges from $0$ to $2\pi$. Is that doable?

Comment: Is it my feeling or the formula for $z^i$ seems wrong?

Comment: @SineoftheTime Seems wrong. Would suggest: $z^i=e^{i\log z}\,,\;(e^{it})^i=e^{iit}=e^{-t}\,.$

Comment: OP, are you sure $\operatorname{Log}(e^{it})=it$ for all $t$? (I mean, what is the branch of your complex logarithm?)

Comment: $z^i=\exp(i\,Logz)$ maybe... Find its definition in the internet.

Comment: @SangchulLee I'm using principle branch.

Comment: Regardless of the branch chosen, your contour integration crosses the branch cut, where the function is discontinuous. You need take that into account. Kurt G.'s comment about the integral in $dt$ no being a contour integral over $C$, but rather a path integration over an interval on the real line is correct (though he has the wrong interval - that depends on your branch, and his cuts along the positive real line, not the negative real line).